# replace '.0' from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a csv file that needs some cleanup. I want to remove '.0' that sometimes shows up in my columns. But no matter what I tried it gives me back errors or removes everything:

```
Pos;ArtNo;Netto;RechnNo;LiefeNo
100;3441223;820,4;1122;555.0
200;3441223;820,4;1122;555.0
300;1492133;224,88;123.0;2200
400;7000061;8,99;12000;2200
500;7003581;2,09;1111.0;100
```

how it should look like :

```
Pos;ArtNo;Netto;RechnNo;LiefeNo
100;3441223;820,4;1122;555
200;3441223;820,4;1122;555
300;1492133;224,88;123;2200
400;7000061;8,99;12000;2200
500;7003581;2,09;1111;100
```

I tried :

```
cols = ['ArtNo','RechnNo','LiefeNo']
file_in[cols] = file_in[cols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('.0'))
```

that removed all zeros which is not what I want

I tried also :

```
file_in[cols] = file_in[cols].astype(str).replace('.0','')
```

and

```
file_in[cols] = file_in[cols].astype(str).str.replace('.0','')
```

which gave me error "**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str**"

I really don't know what else to do :/

**EDIT** I also tried replace using lambda:

```
file_in[cols] = file_in[cols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.0','))
```

did not worked also

**EDIT 2** can't use INT since my columns can sometimes have strings not only numbers

Comment: `df[col].astype(int)`?

Comment: I can't use that , since the columns can sometimes have strings..Example for column "RechnNo" it could be **abc** and not **123**

Comment: How about using `'\.0'` instead of `'.0'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Note the `\` before `.0`

```
file_in[cols] = file_in[cols].astype(str).replace('\.0*$','', regex=True)
```

---

**Explain**:
`df.replace` defaults to `regex=False`. On `regex=False`, it considers the whole word. To make it consider each character, we must set `regex=True`. In regex, character `.` is considered as the matching pattern of any character. To force regex consider it as literal `.`, we need to escape it with `\`. That is the reason we need `\.0`

Comment: worked like a charm :D ...but can you please explain me why use of '\' worked .. not really sure I understand this quite right

Comment: @AmilaBečirović `.` matches any character (that's why in my original answer, it was removing more characters than I intended). If you want to match a dot, you need to add a backslash (`\\`) before it (a.k.a. "escape it")

Comment: @AmilaBečirović: I added explanation

Comment: thank you, didn't know that **.** is considered as the matching pattern

Comment: There seems to be one issue here, it would convert "2.09" to "29".

Comment: @Philippe: you are right. I edited and added the end of string anchor to handle that case :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
file_in[cols] = file_in[cols].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: removed all of zeros... from "3300" i got "33" ..I need "3300" to stay the same

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the dot. Can you try now, @AmilaBečirović ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
file_in[cols] = file_in[cols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.0',''))
```

forgot a ' no?

Comment: this code gives back error : **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'**

Answer (score 0):

Complete program:

```
import re
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    print(re.sub('\.0(?=[;\s])','',fd.read()), end='')

""" call with : python test.py input
"""
```